# PHP Automatic screenshot without loading the DOM

Tags: javascript, php, jpeg, screenshot

I have a website for professional purposes which is displaying some text and graphs (using Google Charts). 
I will take an example of one page : like 'http://mywebsite/board.php'
Let say google chart is inside one div in that page 
     div id='chart'

So my point is I want to run automatically using crontab (every morning 5am CET), some scripts which will screenshot that div where id ='chart' and get a .jpg of the chart.
My idea is then to use that .jpg for automatic email reporting using $email object from php.

Could someone please help me out and give some ideas on how to perform that task?

Comment: Did you have a look at the section *Related* on the right? You may find the answer to your question there ;-)

Comment: You cannot do this with php alone. You would need to either use a headless browser (phantomjs is a good one) or an external api (that will do the same, but charge you for the convenience)

Comment: Yes I looked at but my concern in my case is I am not loading the DOM! I mean how to screenshot a div (where the chart is) by automatic script using like crontab.

Comment: Hi Steve, OK If I cannot do it with php, I am ok with Javascript as well, as long as I can perform automatically that task. I will look at phantomjs and see if it can fits.Thanks for advice.

Comment: If you are doing this only once a day, then you could probably use the browsershots api for free: https://browshot.com/features